# SAPui5 create simple sap.m.ComboBox

Tags: javascript, xml, data-binding, combobox, sapui5

I have a simple model that I want to bind to a sap.m.ComboBox. The data look like this:

```
(2) ["Tabelle1", "Tabelle2"]
0: "Tabelle1"
1: "Tabelle2"
```

What I do is this:

```
... some unimportant stuff before...    
var sheets = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sheetNames);
var comboBox = that.getView().byId("selectSheet");
comboBox.setModel(sheets);
var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item();
comboBox.bindItems("/sheets", oItemTemplate)
```

the comboBox gets created in my XML view:

```
<m:ComboBox id="selectSheet" items="{path: '/sheets'}" change="onSheetSelected">
    <core:Item />
</m:ComboBox>
```

After setting the Model or binding the Items nothing happens.. I feel like that's some simple coding that I'm doing wrong here. Please advise me how to do this. The ComboBox should end up with two simple choices "Tabelle1" and "Tabelle2".

**Update with suggested solution**

```
var sheetNames =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(wb.SheetNames));
var mappedNames = _.map(sheetNames, name => { return {Name: name}});
var sheets = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(mappedNames);
var comboBox = that.getView().byId("selectSheet");
var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
     text : '{Name}'
    });
comboBox.setModel(sheets);
comboBox.bindItems("/mappedNames", oItemTemplate)
```

Mapped names now looks like this:

> ```
> (2) 0: {Name: "Tabelle1"} 1: {Name: "Tabelle2"} length: 2
> ```

Comment: try to add the `text` and `key` attribut to your Item

Comment: also just forget about the js part set your model to the view then do the binding in the xml, its better for readabilty

Comment: @Erch but I don't have any "text" or "key" part in my model. There are no objects, only strings..
I tried the way with XML but the "sheets" model doesn't get set onInit, so my view doesn'T seem to get the data..

Comment: text and key arent the properties of your model, they are properties of the control.... would look like that for you:  <core:Item  key="{/Name}" text="{/Name}"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide a template that specifies what an item should look like in the ComboBox

**Create Binding in Javascript:**

Contoller:

```
var sheetNames = {myList : [{ Name : "Tabelle1"}, {Name : "Tabelle2"}]};
var sheets = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sheetNames);
var comboBox = that.getView().byId("selectSheet");
var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({

    text : '{Name}' // here goes your binding for the property "Name" of your item
});

comboBox.setModel(sheets);
comboBox.bindItems("/myList", oItemTemplate);
```

View:

**Create Binding in XML**:

controller:

```
var sheetNames = {myList : [{ Name : "Tabelle1"}, {Name : "Tabelle2"}]};
var sheets = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sheetNames);
var comboBox = that.getView().byId("selectSheet");

comboBox.setModel(sheets);
```

view:

```
<m:ComboBox id="selectSheet" items="{path: '/myList'}">
    <core:Item text="{Name}"/> </m:ComboBox>
```

Comment: there is no "Name" in my SheetNames.. So how would I access this

Comment: but you need objects in your list. you can map them before do the binding:

var list = ["Tabelle1", "Tabelle2"];
var mappedList = list.map(function(tableName){ return { Name : tableName}; });

Comment: ok I see! I added an update to my question to show how I tried to implement your solution but it's still not binding any data.. seems strange :O

Comment: The data you set in the model is a list. But you have to set an object. As in the example above. There is an object with the property "myList" which contains the list as value.
The absolute path in the binding points to this list

--> comboBox.bindItems("/myList", oItemTemplate)

Comment: In your case it would be:

var mappedNames = _.map(sheetNames, name => { return {Name: name}});
var data = { "mappedNames" : mappedNames };
var sheets = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data );